# Google Chrome - z-index issue on absolutely positioned DIVs

Tags: css, google-chrome, z-index

So I have an "in-development" website and I'm seeing a weird issue in Google Chrome (Edge/Internet Explorer is not showing this bug, but works as intended, which is a first!)

The two "Next" and "Previous" controls for cycling through the header images have a z-index of 666 and are floated left and right, but it seems that Google Chrome is not detecting a) the hover event, b) the click (as far as I can tell). I don't know if this is related to the menu at the bottom of the header...

Any help would be much appreciated!

CSS Code below:

```
#header #coverControls-prev,
#header #coverControls-next {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    opacity: 0.25;
    text-align: center;

    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out, background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 666;
}

#header #coverControls-prev:hover,
#header #coverControls-next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    opacity: 1;
}

#header #coverControls-prev {
    float: left;
    clear: none;
}

#header #coverControls-next {
    float: right;
    clear: none;
}

#header #coverControls-prev p,
#header #coverControls-next p {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50%;

    width: 100%;

    font-size: 10vmin;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 667;
}

#menu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: block;

    padding: 5px 2vw;
    height: 3em;
    width: 100vw;

    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #000000;

    z-index: 777;
}
```

Website in question: http://dev1.deliriousdreams.co.uk/

Comment: Try display:block on the a element

Comment: @Giri - Adding this in Dev Tools in Chrome doesn't seem to resolve the issue. I'm at work so unable to directly edit the site to test at present. I've added the URL so you can see the full thing.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your a tags in css. Your anchor tag needs a width and height. And `display:block` allows you to add width and height for an anchor tag.

```
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
display: block;
```